# Invalidate a Restangular cache response

Tags: angularjs, get, restangular

I have this code so my GET requests are cached.

```
RestangularConfigurer.setDefaultHttpFields({cache: true});
```

I would like to invalidate the responses after an hour. How is it done?

Answer (score 0):

`$cacheFactory.get('http').remove('http://urlToRemove')`

Of course, your controller needs to inject $cacheFactory to get this.